# What does READ_CONTROL mean in the Security event log?

Tags: logging, log-files, windows-event-log

I have been asked to create audit record of file accesses.  By the log is simply overwhelming.  A single double click of a text file opening in notepad creates more than 10 log entries with Event Id 4663. I see a READ_CONTROL access many times.  What is this and which access permission generates this?

I want to trim down the data collection and log only those that reflect an actual opening of a file to read or write.

This is on a Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to do this is to filter for Event IDs 4656 (Opening of a file) and 4658 (Closing of a file) along with 4663; this way you can see who opened/closed the file and the corresponding READ_CONTROL that gets logged along with those events when access permissions are actually used.

Here's a great reference:  https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4663

Let me know if that doesn't work for you or if I'm not addressing your concern and I can be more specific.

Comment: Thanks, but what does READ_CONTROL actually refer to?

Comment: In short, it's what happens when a user actually tries to modify or write and the file checks to see if the user is allowed to do that.  What happens, is that the user's credentials are checked against the SACL/ACL (Security Access List, or Access List) to see if the user actually has permissions to use the file/folder.  READ_CONTROL stems from this very example.  4656 will show up in the Event Viewer whether or not the user has access to a file; so will the 4658.  Because anyone can TRY to open the file so 4656 gets recorded, but READ_CONTROL happens after the open.  Hope it makes sense.